# Cómo corregir conexion a mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer la conexión de mi proyecto a la base de datos.

```
public class Conexion {

private String USUARIO = "";
private String CONTRASENA = "";
private String HOST = "localhost:8080";
private String PORT = "3306";
private String DATABASE = "ingreso";
private String CLASSNAME = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private String URL = "jdbc:mysql://" + HOST + ": " + PORT + "/" + DATABASE;
private Connection con;

public Conexion() {
            try {
                   Class.forName(CLASSNAME);
                   con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, CONTRASENA);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                       System.out.println("ERROR " + e);
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR " + e);
             }
    }

    public Connection getConexion() {
       return con;
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           Conexion con = new Conexion();
    }}
```

Pero me arroja este error a la hora de compilar:

> ERROR com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8080: 3306"'.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Por favor no agregues tu códitgo como imagen, edita y hazlo como texto

Comment: localhost:8080 esta diciendo que se conecte a localhost por el puerto 8080, y luego le decis que use el puerto 3306.. por cual puerto queres ir???

Comment: como te dice crrlos, ese es el primer error luego está  mal tu HOST no debe ir con el puerto 8080

Answer (score 0):

En la variable host estas poniendo el puerto, y cuando construyes la URL de nuevo la vuelves a poner, deja en host solo "localhost" y en el port ya lo dejas por el puerto que este recibiendo la conexión